# Windows 10 Internet Explorer is not working with old VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, windows-10

I wrote code in VBA a couple years ago to open a website in IE and fill in textboxes with data from an excel file. Unfortunately I am using windows 10 now and this program is not working anymore. It opens the website with no problem, but cannot transpose the data into the textboxes. It simply opens the website and stalls (no data is entered).

The program still works in IE in windows 7, without any problem. I tried multiple laptops with windows 10 and the problem reoccurs.

I honestly don't know how to fix this.

```
DoEvents
WebAddress = "CONFIDENTIAL URL HERE" & WebID & "&t=" 

        Dim IE As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.Navigate WebAddress
  IE.Visible = True
  While IE.busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend

  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4))

  IE.Document.All("Response_123").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
```

The last line of code should transfer data from the excel file to the textbox in internet explorer, however nothing happens and the textbox remains blank. Do I need to change anything in my code to account for windows 10 IE?

Comment: Is `Response_123` defined/assigned anywhere?

Comment: If you cannot share the URL, you should at least share the HTML that you try to interact with. Also, you should show how `Response_123` is defined as @MathieuGuindon suggests.

Comment: Also, why the initial DoEvents? And use .Navigate2 and after that line use a proper page load wait of While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend. And document.All is rarely (if ever) an efficient and desirable method for targeting an element.

Comment: Voting to close for lack of a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can see that your code was not written in an efficient way. For an alternative approach, You can refer example below which is working fine with Windows 10.

```
Dim IE As Object

Sub demo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.html"


    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    wait 1
    IE.Document.getElementById("firstname").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    wait 1
    IE.Document.getElementById("lastname").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    wait 1
    IE.Document.getElementById("submit_btn").Click

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub wait(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

If we talk about your above posted code than you can try to put the break point on that line and try to debug the code. Check that Which value contained by Cell B5 and check whether that line get execute successfully or not. For testing purpose, try to assign static value to that textbox.

Comment: Deepak.. I changed my code to exactly what you have, but instead of "first name" using the ID that shows up when I right click > inspect on the textbox. It's still not filling in the textboxes unfortunately.. they remain blank.