# Windows 10 IE is not working with old VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, windows-10

I wrote code in VBA a couple years ago to open a website in IE and fill in textboxes with data from an Excel file. Unfortunately I am using windows 10 now and this program is not working any more. It opens the website with no problem, but cannot transpose the data into the textboxes. It simply opens the website and stalls (no data is entered).

The program still works in IE in Windows 7, without any problem. I tried multiple laptops with Windows 10 and the problem reoccurs.

I tried changing my code at the end from `IE.Document.All("Response_123").Value` to `IE.Document.getElementById("Response_123")` to see if that would copy my Excel values into the textbox, but it just remained blank.

```
Sub test()
Dim IE As Object

WebAddress = "https://CONFIDENTIAL_URL.com/"


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate WebAddress

  While IE.busy
    DoEvents  'wait until IE is done loading page.
  Wend

  Application.wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4))

  IE.Document.getElementById("Response_123").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
End Sub
```

I would expect the value in my Excel sheet at B5 to be copied into the textbox that has ID "Response_123" (obtained from right clicking textbox > inspect), but it does not copy anything and remains blank. Again, I have no problem getting my code to work in Windows 7.

Comment: Please post at least a part of HTML code containing target element with all elements it nested into up to `<body>`. Compare HTML from Win 7 and 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Internet Explorer is not working with old VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224550/windows-10-internet-explorer-is-not-working-with-old-vba-code)

Comment: This appears to duplicate your earlier question. Since they seem to be focussing on the same problem, you could close this one, and then post your answer on the earlier question. I am glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution. Nothing is wrong with the above code, it was simply the security settings in IE. By default they are set to Medium-High, so I changed them to Medium and the code worked fine.

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved your issue. I suggest you to mark that solution as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in similar kind of issues. Other thing I want to inform you that you not need to create a new thread for same issue and delete the old one. You need to continue your discussion on the same thread. Ref:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224550/windows-10-ie-is-not-working-with-old-vba-code-help-please