# Run-time'-2147023170 (800706be)': Automation error The remote procedure call failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue while sending Whatsapp messages to my customers using excel vba, everything was working fine till I have updated the windows 10, then the code is broken

```
Option Explicit
Sub WhatsAppMsg()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim strip As String
Dim strPhoneNumber As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strPostData As String
Dim IE As Object

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow

    strPhoneNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    strMessage = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Copy
    
        
        strPostData = "whatsapp://send?phone=" & strPhoneNumber & "&text=" & strMessage
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.navigate strPostData
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
                
                
        Call SendKeys("^v")

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
        
        Call SendKeys("{ENTER}", True)
        

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553070/vba-internetexplorer-application-object-hang and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240485/windows-10-ie-is-not-working-with-old-vba-code

Comment: I've tried the same method but did not work

Comment: Okay, so for "code is broken", what do you mean exactly? Is there an error? What kind, and which line? Or is there some other non-error difference between your expected outcome and the actual outcome? (if so, describe specifics). For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, this helps the SO community help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when I run the code this error message will be shown
'Run-time'-2147023170 (800706be)': Automation error The remote procedure call failed'

Answer (score 1):

I would confirm that you are logged into your WhatsApp account before running the Macro.
I received a similar error when trying to populate PDFs from an excel macro. It turns out I wasn't logged into Adobe. Once I was logged into Adobe the error went away and the Macro ran as expected.